# SQL Update a table from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I am a complete beginner to SQL Server, and I have reached my limit.

Currently I am using a script to update a table from another table using a column. Since both databases are assigned to 2 different 3rd party software, I created a `.bat` script to use for task manager in windows server, that way it can update every 10 minutes.

While this is tested and works, I feel there has to be a way to create a relationship between the two databases without having to use the task.

```
UPDATE therefore.dbo.thecat51
SET num_factura = 
 (SELECT therefore.dbo.documentos.num_factura
 FROM therefore.dbo.Documentos
 WHERE therefore.dbo.thecat51.num_albaran=therefore.dbo.documentos.num_albaran)
WHERE therefore.dbo.thecat51.num_albaran = 
 ( SELECT therefore.dbo.documentos.num_albaran
 FROM therefore.dbo.Documentos
 WHERE therefore.dbo.thecat51.num_Albaran = therefore.dbo.documentos.num_albaran)
```

Also, we are using SQL Server Express, so I don't have the option to create a scheduled job.

Comment: linked server is probably what you are looking at -> https://www.google.fr/search?q=linked+server+sql+server&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=J0pIV6TBE-2v8weI1oLoAg

Answer (score 0):

You can do the `UPDATE` with an `INNER JOIN` to perform the update you need:

```
UPDATE A SET
    num_factura = B.num_factura
FROM therefore.dbo.thecat51 A
    INNER JOIN therefore.dbo.Documentos B
        ON A.num_albaran = B.num_albaran
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `INNER JOIN` between your two tables.  At the time I posted this, you had not told us which RDBMS you are using so I will give answers for SQL Server and MySQL:

**SQL Server:**

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.num_factura = t2.num_factura
FROM therefore.dbo.thecat51 AS t1
INNER JOIN therefore.dbo.Documentos AS t2
    ON t1.num_albaran = t2.num_albaran
```

**MySQL:**

```
UPDATE therefore.dbo.thecat51 AS t1
INNER JOIN therefore.dbo.Documentos AS t2
    ON t1.num_albaran = t2.num_albaran
SET t1.num_factura = t2.num_factura
```

Comment: I tried and it works , but it works the same way , meaning , i need to manually update the table , or create the script that executes every 10 minutes . What i was asking is a way to link the two tables so that they update automatically everytime a value is added.

Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but i've been doing other work. I searched about triggers and that seems to be what i'm looking for.