# Update a table from another table using subselect

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, subquery

Using postgresql I have a table `A` with columns `company_name`, `department_name`, some other data, and `department`.

I have another table `B` with simply `company_name`, `department_name`, and `did`. (This are two tables with a relationship in between, but I made a view from it to make syntax easier.)

I want to set `A.department` to `B.did` of the row with matching names. It is a part of a normalization process.

According to this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server) I tried:

```
UPDATE A 
SET department=did 
FROM A AS A 
INNER JOIN B 
  ON A.company_name = B.company_name AND A.department_name=B.department_name;
```

But I get the result, that `A.department` for all rows are set to the same value.

(I have also tried different syntax from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484487/sql-update-a-table-from-another-table), but get syntax errors as expected.)

Why isn't that working and more specifically, why aren't the rows matched properly. When I try a `SELECT` on that join, I get the expected result.

Comment: Both questions you link to are for SQL Server, not for Postgres

Comment: Ys, I did not expect more than a minor syntactical difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you want to write the query like this:

```
UPDATE A 
    SET department = B.did 
FROM B 
WHERE A.company_name = B.company_name AND
      A.department_name = B.department_name;
```

When you mention the `A` table in the `FROM` clause, it is a *separate* reference to `A`, nothing to do with the table being updated.  The simple solution is to refer to the table only once.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: this is also [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html): "*Note that the target table must not appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join*"

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I tried it a similar way found in the referred Q&A, which seemed to be intuitive to me. Therefore I guessed to have a pure syntactical problem and did not see the hint in the docs.