# How Update a table from 2 variables of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have 2 table, in table `A` I have `id_A` and `region_A`, in table 2 I have `id_B` and `region_B`

I want to set `region_A = region_B` when `id_A` is equal `id_B`

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484487/sql-update-a-table-from-another-table)

and tried :

```
UPDATE  A  SET  A.`region` =   B.region  
FROM  A   
inner join B    on A.id_a = B.id_b
```

I got this error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT * FROM A  inner join B on A.id_a' at line 1

How can update my table A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is SQL Server syntax. Try this instead:

```
UPDATE Α AS t1
INNER JOIN Β AS t2
    ON t1.region = t2.region
SET t1.id_a = t2.id_b
```